# Does any body know what is the meaning of SHA-256 check sums in downloading android studio?

Tags: android-studio, download, checksum, sha

If you go for installing android studo you can see some check sums.
Does any body know what is the meaning of SHA-256 check sums and how it is working?

[image]

Ho can see it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).

Comment: Usually is to check if the file isn't corrupted, calculating the hash on the downloaded file should match the provided in the site

Comment: Is there any document link for that?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/shasum . The easier way to do is to download the checksum file. This file contains `<a name> <a checksum>`. You just place the check sum file side by side with the downloaded file that will be checked and run `shasum -c <checksumfile>` replacing `<checksumfile>` by the name of the checksum file. If the checksum fail it will report the error.